# Why am I not able to see the down vote given for my answer?

Tags: support, downvotes

I gave an answer to the question 
`How can I use wait() as a non-blocking command in Unix?`
I am seeing the downvotes on my activity page. But I am not able to see the downvote on the question page. Please see the screen shots taken on 18th October, 2019 (10:19 AM).

[image: Activity page showing down votes]

[image: Question Page not showing down vote]

I contacted the support team, they told me "Your post was downvoted and there is a downvote displaying for your answer.". Can someone please explain why am I not able to see the down vote on question page?

Comment: Your answer shows a score of -1 for me.

Comment: @Turamarth But why am I not able to see it.?

Comment: Turamarth seems -1 because they're in the group seeing -1. You (OP) and me are two of the many people in the group seeing 0. It's not a bug, nor something you can fix or chose, it's an A/B test with a few more days left to live.

Comment: And all of meta is looking forward to when it ends. I get how featuring the post about it would ruin the A/B test but it does cause quite a bit of confusion.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl    User was able see to down vote (-1) in that question. How is it related to this question? I am not seeing the downvotes.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula read Shog's answer. It covers what you need to know, regardless of which side of the vote you're on.